# Using Ninject as IoC for EasyNetQ

Tags: ninject, easynetq

i'm using EasyNetQ library in my project and I would like to use Ninject as IoC Container for EasyNetQ components.

I created a custom logger in order to log anythong from EasyNetQ:

```
public class LogNothingLogger : IEasyNetQLogger
{
    ...
}
```

And then using the Ninject extension in my main function:

```
public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Container creation and custom logger registration
            IKernel cointainer = new StandardKernel();
            cointainer.Bind<IEasyNetQLogger>().To<LogNothingLogger>();

            // Register Ninject as IoC Container for EasyNetQ
            cointainer.RegisterAsEasyNetQContainerFactory();

            // Create bus
            using (IBus bus = RabbitHutch.CreateBus("host=localhost"))
            {
                // Do something with bus...
            }
        }
    }
```

But I get the following exception:

```
Ninject.ActivationException was unhandled
More than one matching bindings are available.
Matching bindings:
  1) binding from IEasyNetQLogger to LogNothingLogger
  2) binding from IEasyNetQLogger to method
Activation path:
  2) Injection of dependency IEasyNetQLogger into parameter logger of constructor of type RabbitBus
  1) Request for RabbitBus

Suggestions:
  1) Ensure that you have defined a binding for IEasyNetQLogger only once.
[...]
```

Am I using this package in the wrong way? Is there any solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As the exception says, there are two bindings for `IEasyNetQLogger`.

I suppose that an ninject extension you are using is already binding an `IEasyNetQLogger`.

You could use Rebind (`IBindingRoot.Rebind<IEasyNetQLogger>()`) to override any existing binding for `IEasyNetQLogger`.

But i would also advise you to look into why the extension is already creating a binding and how it is supposed to be used.

What is the extension you are using?

Edit: i took a glance at https://github.com/mikehadlow/EasyNetQ/tree/master/Source/EasyNetQ.DI.Ninject
and i did not find any binding for `IEasyNetQLogger`. Are you sure you don't have defined an additional `IBindingRoot.Bind<IEasyNetQLogger>().ToMethod(...)` binding?

It could also be `NinjectAdapter.Register<IEasyNetQLogger>(Func<IEasyNetQLogger> ...)`.

If you have not done so, then the EasyNetQ is already registering a logger by `NinjectAdapter.Register<IEasyNetQLogger>(Func<IEasyNetQLogger> ...)`.

As before, you can use `Rebind(..)` to replace the binding (which must be done after the original binding was created!) or look into how it is supposed to work.

---

Of course you might also just want to skip the binding since you only created one for "log nothing logger"...

Comment: Hi BatteryBackupUnit,

i tried with Rebind but i Still get the error. If i do not bind anything to the logger EasyNetQ keep using the default one.
It is like the statement `CreateBus` is still binding its own components after ninject ones. There is a strange comment in the Estension test [link](https://github.com/mikehadlow/EasyNetQ/blob/master/Source/EasyNetQ.DI.Tests/NinjectAdapterTests.cs):
`Ninject doesn't allow more than one registration of a service, it throws an exception`
It seems still an open issue.

Comment: In  that case EasyNetQ is creating a binding after you have called rebind. You will need to figure out how EasyNetQ logging is supposed to be configured. You need to find out who's calling `NinjectAdapter.Register<TService>(Func<...`. Maybe there is also some way you are supposed to configure EasyNetQ - not ninject- for logging. Try removing your binding and use `IResolutionRoot.Get<IEasyNetQLogger>` - see what it returns?